# W3C validation error: 'document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "ins", "del", "map", "button" start-tag'

Tags: xhtml, w3c-validation

My source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it" lang="it">
    <head>
        <title>Hi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
        <a href="product_displayer.cgi">
          <div style="background-image: url('../res/images/background.jpeg')">
              <img src="../res/images/products/thumbnails/image.png" alt="hello"/>
              <p>Hello hello hello</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I try to validate the code, the W3C validator giving me this error:

> document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "ins", "del", "map", "button" start-tag

How can I solve it?

Comment: Best to just put `<!DOCTYPE html>` (and drop the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="it"` part). XHTML 1.0 is long obsolete now.

Comment: @sideshowbarker You assume that the OP's file has a MIME type of `text/html`. In that case, dropping the xmlns is OK. However, if this is an XHTML file (with MIME type `application/xhtml+xml`) the browser definitely needs this attribute!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>     <a href="product_displayer.cgi">
>       <div style="background-image: url('../res/images/background.jpeg')">
> ```

In XHTML 1, you cannot have a div inside an anchor.

Either don't use a div (or a paragraph) or use HTML 5 which does allow that.